# Active Model Serializers and Chewy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I've got a Rails 4 project using AMS and Chewy.

If I define an AMS for default, I'm able to serialise just fine. However, if I use a custom AMS, I get an error: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'read_attribute_for_serialization' for #<Chewy::Query:0x000000060c1da8>)`

Code (works fine):

```
@search = Search.new(params)
@results = @search.query.load
render json: @results
```

Code (breaks):

```
@search = Search.new(params)
@results = @search.query.load
render json: @results, serializer: MySerializer
```

Both the default model serializer I wrote and `MySerializer` are identical. There's nothing fancy in there either.

```
class MySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :my_attribute, :other_attribute

  has_one :thing

end
```

I've tried to monkeypatch Chewy::Query:

```
module Chewy
  class Query
    alias_method :read_attribute_for_serialization, :send
  end
end
```

but I just get `NoMethodError (undefined method 'my_attribute' for #<Chewy::Query:0x000000069af5c8>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it should be

`render json: @results, each_serializer: MySerializer`

since it's trying to serialise a collection with a single-object serialiser.